# use 2 vertical stackviews within scrollview that increase height according to inner views

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uistackview

I'm trying to create a screen with a scrollview holding various views and also two vertical stackviews using auto layout and constraints, while adding items to both stack views programmatically.
The problem is that I cannot make both stack views be as large as the views within them.
If I don't add any height constraints to the stack views, the inspector gives me a warning and not all the views are displayed within the screen.
If I add enough height to the stack views, For cases when the height is too big, I will see blank spaces in the screen.
How can I cause the stack views to have height matching the items on the screen while making sure all the other views on the screen will be displayed?

I added 2 screenshots, the first with a small amount of items in both stacks when the screen looks good, the second with a lot of items in both stacks and you can see the result I described

Also I added the code generating the result in the screenshots in the link below

[sample project](https://github.com/guylis/swift_test/)

[image]

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple options...

1) Don't give the stack views height constraints, and ignore Storyboard / IB error/warning (it's only telling you the layout is not complete yet - it has no way of knowing you will satisfy the constraints at run-time).

2) Give the stack views height constraints of 0, and set the Priority of the height constraints to 250 - that will allow auto-layout to increase the height when needed.

3) Give the stack views height constraints, but set them as **Placeholders**:

[image]

That will satisfy Storyboard, but will not affect the heights at run-time.

---

***Edit***

After comments, screenshots and taking a look at your project, the problem was that your constraints were not-quite-right, resulting in the scrollView's ***content*** not scrolling all the way.

Couple notes that may help:

1) Give each element a unique name... much easier to think about

> "linkTextView as a subview of containerSubView, which is a subview of mainSubView, which is a subview of mainContentView"

as opposed to

> "view as a subview of view, which is a subview of view, which is a subview of view"

2) During development, give your views contrasting background colors... makes it much easier to see the layout frames at runtime.

Here's a screenshot of how your layout should be constrained:

[image]

and here is the output, scrolled to the bottom (I added a label after "item100" with a key to the views' background colors):

[image]

and, here is the source to the Storyboard (just right-click on the storyboard file, select `Open As -> Source Code`, and replace the entire content with the following):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="15505" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <device id="retina6_1" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="15510"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="swiftTraining2" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="896"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="haV-jN-E91">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="44" width="414" height="818"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="13w-Sm-aLB" userLabel="Main Content View">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="10" width="414" height="818"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Lk9-K2-0eH" userLabel="Top Stack View">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="200"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="200" placeholder="YES" id="aop-qh-b8I"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                            </stackView>
                                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="7od-Vy-8zM" userLabel="Main SubView">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="5" y="205" width="404" height="608"/>
                                                <subviews>
                                                    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="hw6-MO-6K5" userLabel="Stack Link Container View">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="5" y="5" width="394" height="598"/>
                                                        <subviews>
                                                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="uku-Xj-j12">
                                                                <rect key="frame" x="5" y="5" width="384" height="563"/>
                                                            </stackView>
                                                            <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" text="Link" textAlignment="natural" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="bct-cc-3xh">
                                                                <rect key="frame" x="5" y="573" width="384" height="20"/>
                                                                <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
                                                                <constraints>
                                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="20" id="uB8-jy-STI"/>
                                                                </constraints>
                                                                <color key="textColor" systemColor="labelColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                                                                <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences" textContentType="url"/>
                                                            </textView>
                                                        </subviews>
                                                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemYellowColor" red="1" green="0.80000000000000004" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                        <constraints>
                                                            <constraint firstItem="uku-Xj-j12" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="hw6-MO-6K5" secondAttribute="top" constant="5" id="9LG-gX-H3R"/>
                                                            <constraint firstItem="uku-Xj-j12" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="hw6-MO-6K5" secondAttribute="leading" constant="5" id="K42-bH-xHE"/>
                                                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="uku-Xj-j12" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="5" id="Lap-sB-h8E"/>
                                                            <constraint firstItem="bct-cc-3xh" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="uku-Xj-j12" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="5" id="PdU-Pu-n8y"/>
                                                            <constraint firstItem="bct-cc-3xh" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="hw6-MO-6K5" secondAttribute="leading" constant="5" id="Xm4-fL-hzr"/>
                                                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="bct-cc-3xh" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="5" id="hF9-TI-LZN"/>
                                                            <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="bct-cc-3xh" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="5" id="kXT-Wg-s1z"/>
                                                        </constraints>
                                                    </view>
                                                </subviews>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.45009386540000001" green="0.98132258650000004" blue="0.4743030667" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="hw6-MO-6K5" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="5" id="JG5-Fh-2k6"/>
                                                    <constraint firstItem="hw6-MO-6K5" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="7od-Vy-8zM" secondAttribute="leading" constant="5" id="ibg-UH-XTf"/>
                                                    <constraint firstItem="hw6-MO-6K5" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="7od-Vy-8zM" secondAttribute="top" constant="5" id="kuH-dl-gXT"/>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="hw6-MO-6K5" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="5" id="qHo-jD-cgV"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                            </view>
                                        </subviews>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemTealColor" red="0.35294117650000001" green="0.7843137255" blue="0.98039215690000003" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstItem="Lk9-K2-0eH" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="13w-Sm-aLB" secondAttribute="top" id="1A1-Yr-m3q"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="7od-Vy-8zM" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="5" id="5rm-XQ-2qJ"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="Lk9-K2-0eH" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="13w-Sm-aLB" secondAttribute="leading" id="FGH-Z3-RpE"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="Lk9-K2-0eH" secondAttribute="trailing" id="I6d-e1-OKc"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="7od-Vy-8zM" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="5" id="WXH-MT-LYJ"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="7od-Vy-8zM" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="13w-Sm-aLB" secondAttribute="leading" constant="5" id="r68-3o-LzV"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="7od-Vy-8zM" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Lk9-K2-0eH" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="5" id="x4w-xp-OAQ"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </view>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemRedColor" red="1" green="0.23137254900000001" blue="0.18823529410000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="13w-Sm-aLB" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="10" id="3uZ-9Q-Syi"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="13w-Sm-aLB" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="-10" id="7cN-wV-qLW"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="13w-Sm-aLB" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="haV-jN-E91" secondAttribute="width" id="EEs-NO-GjV"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="13w-Sm-aLB" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="haV-jN-E91" secondAttribute="leading" id="hwr-sh-sz8"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="13w-Sm-aLB" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="haV-jN-E91" secondAttribute="top" constant="10" id="stQ-Nw-f8o"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="13w-Sm-aLB" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="haV-jN-E91" secondAttribute="height" priority="250" id="xq5-Ng-LZM"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="contentLayoutGuide" id="2gK-OB-LB9"/>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="frameLayoutGuide" id="3NE-oL-tLQ"/>
                            </scrollView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="haV-jN-E91" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="leading" id="BuP-KW-1bP"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="haV-jN-E91" secondAttribute="trailing" id="gFi-Mo-tEp"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="haV-jN-E91" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="top" id="tDm-TP-XSG"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="haV-jN-E91" secondAttribute="bottom" id="vd7-z3-iwb"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="6Tk-OE-BBY"/>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="linkTextView" destination="bct-cc-3xh" id="Gq2-NM-Hcn"/>
                        <outlet property="stack2" destination="uku-Xj-j12" id="Jkh-gK-WNx"/>
                        <outlet property="stackView" destination="Lk9-K2-0eH" id="AXb-Za-4To"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="131.8840579710145" y="123.88392857142857"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

---

**Edit 2**

This Storyboard source gives the same layout, but without using "containing" views. As you see, the controller has a scroll view, which contains only two stack views and a text view. No "containing" views:

[image]

Storyboard source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="16096" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="16087"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="swiftTraining2" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="haV-jN-E91">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Lk9-K2-0eH" userLabel="Top Stack View">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="8" width="375" height="200"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="200" placeholder="YES" id="aop-qh-b8I"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </stackView>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="uku-Xj-j12">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="15" y="220" width="345" height="200"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="200" placeholder="YES" id="l5I-jk-CSZ"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </stackView>
                                    <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" text="Link" textAlignment="natural" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="bct-cc-3xh">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="15" y="428" width="345" height="20"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="20" id="uB8-jy-STI"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                        <color key="textColor" systemColor="labelColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                                        <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences" textContentType="url"/>
                                    </textView>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.83234566450000003" blue="0.47320586440000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="bct-cc-3xh" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="uku-Xj-j12" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="9m5-Vv-236"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Lk9-K2-0eH" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="2gK-OB-LB9" secondAttribute="leading" id="DTb-E5-Cu5"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Lk9-K2-0eH" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="2gK-OB-LB9" secondAttribute="trailing" id="O7S-Wk-bj0"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="2gK-OB-LB9" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="bct-cc-3xh" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="15" id="Pmk-yq-TQ8"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="2gK-OB-LB9" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="bct-cc-3xh" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="RdG-fP-fRO"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Lk9-K2-0eH" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="3NE-oL-tLQ" secondAttribute="width" id="YRg-O2-9uu"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="bct-cc-3xh" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="2gK-OB-LB9" secondAttribute="leading" constant="15" id="Z1N-f5-SSG"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="2gK-OB-LB9" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="uku-Xj-j12" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="15" id="emJ-tp-a8p"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Lk9-K2-0eH" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="2gK-OB-LB9" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="hjJ-5I-6rv"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="uku-Xj-j12" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Lk9-K2-0eH" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="12" id="pEG-bG-p79"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="uku-Xj-j12" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="2gK-OB-LB9" secondAttribute="leading" constant="15" id="tuG-9C-4K1"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="contentLayoutGuide" id="2gK-OB-LB9"/>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="frameLayoutGuide" id="3NE-oL-tLQ"/>
                            </scrollView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="haV-jN-E91" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="leading" id="BuP-KW-1bP"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="haV-jN-E91" secondAttribute="trailing" id="gFi-Mo-tEp"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="haV-jN-E91" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="top" id="tDm-TP-XSG"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="haV-jN-E91" secondAttribute="bottom" id="vd7-z3-iwb"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="6Tk-OE-BBY"/>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="linkTextView" destination="bct-cc-3xh" id="Gq2-NM-Hcn"/>
                        <outlet property="stack2" destination="uku-Xj-j12" id="Jkh-gK-WNx"/>
                        <outlet property="stackView" destination="Lk9-K2-0eH" id="AXb-Za-4To"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="131.8840579710145" y="123.88392857142857"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

The result, directly from your Sample Project:

[image]

Comment: Hi DonMag
thanks for the quick answer, I tried all 3 options and they all generated the same result when I have a lot of items in both stacks - for the first stack to look good, for the second one to show partial items and for the link I have at the bottom of the screen not to be displayed.
I added 2 screenshots to the original post, the first with a small amount of items in both stacks when the screen looks good, the second with a lot of items in both stacks and you can see the result I described
I also added a link to the sample project generating the problem

Comment: @user2679041 - hmmm... I guess you need to describe a bit more what you are trying to do. Do you mean you want the stackViews to scroll when needed, but other elements (such as the "Site Link") to remain visible on the screen? It may be helpful if you post images of the results you ***want*** to get along with the images of what you ***don't*** want.

Comment: Hi @DonMag, I cannot get the screen to act how I like so it's a problem to attach a picture for it. What I would like is to have 2 vertical stack views that you can scroll through them to see all of their elements and in addition I have another text view at the bottom I would like to be displayed when the user scrolls all the way down.
There's requirement I don't understand how to integrate - add the stack layout in a way that will increase as the number of elements on the screen using the constraints, while still showing all other elements in the screen as you scroll through the screen

Comment: hi @DonMag, thank you so much for your answer, sorry for the later reply, it took me a while to get back to this issue, I'll go over your solution that I see after downloading fixed the problem, but I see that you put the second stack view in a separate sub view instead of putting them in the same content view, can you explain the logic behind that and if this is mandatory when adding more that one stack view to a screen?

Comment: @user2679041 - I embedded the stack views in other views, based on the layout from your sample project. See the **Edit 2** at the bottom of my answer for the ***same*** result but using only the two stack views and the text view directly in the scroll view.

Comment: brilliant, I'll go over it to understand what I did wrong in my constraints, thank you